# Which value is the *mean value* in the mean value theorem: the argument, the function, or the derivative?

Tags: calculus, definition

After looking over a few statements and proofs of the real number mean value theorem of single variable calculus of single valued functions, I realized that it is not clear to me what is actually meant by *mean value*.  I understand the proofs.  I just don't know exactly what the name of the theorem means.

For the case of $f\left[x\right]$ continuous on $x\in\left[x_0,x_1\right]$ and differentiable in $x\in\left(x_0,x_1\right),$ and $c\in\left(x_0,x_1\right)$ such that

$$f^\prime\left[c\right]=\frac{f\left[x_1\right]-f\left[x_0\right]}{x_1-x_0},$$

there are three possible values which might be designated the *mean value*. Either $c$, $f\left[c\right]$ or $f^\prime\left[c\right].$  Which one is it?  Are there good names for the other values in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value would be $\,f'(c)\,$.

This makes a lot more sense if you consider the [integral form of MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals) $\,f(c) = \frac {1}{b-a}\int _{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx\,$, where the RHS is indeed the ["*mean value*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function) of $\,f(x)\,$ over $\,[a,b]\,$.

Comment: I believe the answer was correct as originally stated.  Alternatively: $$\,f'(c) = \frac {1}{b-a}\int _{a}^{b}f'(x)\,dx\,$$

Comment: @StevenHatton Right, thank you, rolled back. Your alternative is indeed what I was hinting at.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that $f'(c)$ is the 'mean value' in the theorem.

With some hand-waving, the "average" gradient of the graph of $f$ taken over the interval $(x_0,x_1)$  is $\frac{f\left(x_1\right)-f\left(x_0\right)}{x_1-x_0}$. Whilst the derivative $f'(c)$ may not always equal this value, it has to at some point, because that's the 'mean'.

I don't think there are particular names for the values of $c$ or $f(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the *mean value*  denotes the mean value of $f$ on the interval $[c_0,c_1]$, i.e.  the value of the fraction
$$\frac{f(x_1)-f([x_0)}{x_1-x_0},$$
which is the equivalent of the *average speed*, if $x$ is time, and $f(x)$ is position at a given time.

In terms of kinematics, the *Mean value theorem* asserts that the average speed on a time interval is equal to the instantaneous speed at some time of this time interval, whence the name of the theorem.

Comment: I would have said "velocity", not speed. But this is correct, IMO, and the other answers are off the mark. The content of the MVT is that the mean value, i.e. average rate of change, equals the instantaneous rate of change at  some intermediate point.

Comment: Actually, the MVT gets complicated when dealing with more than 2 dimensions.  For example, on a helical path there is no mean velocity vector between points on the curve.